SP API putListingsItem without issues but getListingsItem return INVALID_ATTRIBUTE with unhelpful message
By using Postman, I've called putListingsItem many times and got response with ACCEPTED status and empty issues array. But when I called getListingsItem of created SKU, it returned the exactly attributes I pushed but not empty issues. The issue response as below:
{
    "sku": "BOX-XR-PATN-1050",
    "summaries": [],
    "attributes": {
        "color": [
            {
                "value": "White",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_type_name": [
            {
                "value": "Color Laser Printer",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_package_weight": [
            {
                "unit": "kilograms",
                "value": 0.5,
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "manufacturer": [
            {
                "value": "Brother",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "model_name": [
            {
                "value": "Color Printer Toner TN-1050",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "bullet_point": [
            {
                "value": "Toner for Brother TN1050 TN-1050 Black Compatible",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "model_number": [
            {
                "value": "BOX-XR-PATN-1050",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "product_description": [
            {
                "value": "The compatible toner for Brother TN-1050 has a print capacity of up to 1,000 pages in black and white at 5% coverage of the A4 sheet. The inks and pigments used for the production of compatible consumables are extremely high-performance and ensure perfect printing performance on paper until the last copy made. Long-lasting prints and ink mixes that do not damage the printer make the compatible Brother TN-1050 toner a toner equivalent in quality and performance to the originals of the brand, only more convenient in terms of cost.",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": [
            {
                "value": "storage",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "brand": [
            {
                "value": "SSC",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "mfg_series_number": [
            {
                "value": "TN1050",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "country_of_origin": [
            {
                "value": "IT",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "merchant_shipping_group": [
            {
                "value": "legacy-template-id",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_name": [
            {
                "value": "Toner for Brother TN1050 TN-1050 Black Compatible",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "list_price": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": 10.0,
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "batteries_required": [
            {
                "value": false,
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_type_keyword": [
            {
                "value": "Toner",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_depth_width_height": [
            {
                "depth": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 5.0
                },
                "width": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 20.0
                },
                "height": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 10.0
                },
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "merchant_suggested_asin": [
            {
                "value": "XRPATN1050",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "condition_type": [
            {
                "value": "new_new",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "number_of_items": [
            {
                "value": 10,
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "item_package_dimensions": [
            {
                "length": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 5.0
                },
                "width": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 10.0
                },
                "height": {
                    "unit": "inches",
                    "value": 20.0
                },
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "size": [
            {
                "value": "5Dx10Wx20L",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "warranty_description": [
            {
                "value": "1 Year Manufacturer",
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "part_number": [
            {
                "value": "BOX-XR-PATN-1050",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ]
    },
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "8105",
            "message": "The data you provided for an attribute is invalid. Please refer the data definitions and resubmit with a valid value.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "categories": [
                "INVALID_ATTRIBUTE"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "offers": [],
    "fulfillmentAvailability": [],
    "procurement": []
}

Is that issue of SP-API or I missed something?

As described into the "Building Listings Management Workflows Guide", after you submit a request through putListingsItem you receive either an ACCEPTED or INVALID status. If it is accepted, it doesn't mean necessarily it is valid, since an asynchronous validation is performed by Amazon.
Best practice is to wait for LISTINGS_ITEM_STATUS_CHANGE or LISTINGS_ITEM_ISSUES_CHANGE notifications and check if the validation was performed correctly.
